# Android record video into a circular buffer and storing it in RAM

Tags: java, android, opencv, video-capture, video-recording

Im looking for a easy way to record video (including audio) into a circular buffer stored in RAM.

So I can leave the video recording it will keep the feed in RAM the last 2 minutes and then have the option to commit it to memory if required.

Unfortunately, I cannot see an easy way to do this. So far I have investigated using:

- MediaRecorder - I could not see a way to store the output data in a
  buffer. Only option is setOutputFile()
- JavaCV FFmpegFrameRecorder - again the constructor for this requires 
  passing in a file.
- android.hardware.Camera.PreviewCallback - this gives a byte array for
  every frame which I could add to a buffer. However, this approach does not provide any audio data.

I feel like there must be a easy way to do this but so far I've not had much luck.
Any help with this would be very appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8974035/video-recording-to-a-circular-buffer-on-android .

Answer (score 1):

[JavaCV](http://code.google.com/p/javacv/) offers `cvCreateCameraCapture()` to open an interface with the camera. **[This code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13391197/176769) demonstrates how to capture frames from the camera and display them on a window.**

The interesting part resides in the `while` loop: every iteration of loop retrieves a single frame from the camera with `cvQueryFrame()`. Note that the data type returned by this function is `IplImage`, and this type is responsible for storing the image grabbed from the camera.

All you need to do is store the `IplImage` returned by `cvQueryFrame()` in your circular buffer.

Comment: Thanks for this. I need the audio data as well, does this approach capture the audio data too?

Comment: OpenCV doesn't deal with audio streams (therefore, neither JavaCV).

Comment: JavaCV handles also audio. Please take a look at FFmpegFrameRecorder, record(..) method. You can create a circular buffer storing the audio samples too.